# get Jitpack as jar but need aar

Tags: android, maven, jitpack

I try to include the [kaltura/player-sdk-native-android](https://github.com/kaltura/player-sdk-native-android) library in my project.

kaltura dosn't provide a compiled version at maven. So I try to include it via [jitpack.io](https://jitpack.io)

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.github.kaltura:player-sdk-native-android:v2.5.4'
}
```

But I get this error message

```
/Users/ralphbergmann/development/android/frameworks/MyApplication/app/build.gradle
Error:Module 'com.github.kaltura:player-sdk-native-android:v2.5.4'
depends on one or more Android Libraries but is a jar
```

When I [open the build log](https://jitpack.io/com/github/kaltura/player-sdk-native-android/v2.5.4/build.log) I can see that the submodules are build as aar but how can I load them via jitpack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a solution for the KalturaSDK integration that worked:

Add a line for each required submodule in your dependencies block:

```
compile 'com.github.kaltura.player-sdk-native-android:playerSDK:v2.5.4'
compile 'com.github.kaltura.player-sdk-native-android:googlemediaframework:v2.5.4'
```